# How to get PR title on a push event in github actions?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions, github-api

On push event, is it possible to get the PR title , so that i can use the same to create a release and tag.

Currently, i am not able to get PR title on push event.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 3):

I actually was in need for a similar use case.
We needed to check if the PR title contained a Jira ticket as part of streamline our workflow.

I got to the following github actions extension
https://github.com/8BitJonny/gh-get-current-pr

Few things to notice:
If in your use case you need to get the PR title and your push event is `pull_request` you can just use `github.head_ref` (see here - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) as you have the information in the context.

However, in my case, my event was just `push` so I didn't have this information.

This is where `gh-get-current-pr` is useful.

add the following to your github actions yaml

```
  steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- uses: 8BitJonny/gh-get-current-pr@1.4.0
  id: PR
  with:
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    # Verbose setting SHA when using Pull_Request event trigger to fix #16
    sha: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
    # Only return if PR is still open
    filterOutClosed: true
- run: echo "Your PR is ${prNumber} and its JSON is ${prJSON}"
  if: success() && steps.PR.outputs.number
  env:
    prNumber: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.number }}
    # JSON object with the full PR object
    prJSON: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr }}
    # Direct access to common PR properties
    prUrl: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_url }}
    prTitle: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_title }}
    prBody: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_body }}
    prCreatedAt: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_created_at }}
    prMergedAt: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_merged_at }}
    prClosedAt: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_closed_at }}
    prLabel: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_labels }}
```

This basically an example on how you can configure environment variables from the PR step output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${{ github.event.push.head_commit.message }}`. See `push` payload in the [Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push).

Comment: I think that is the commit message not the PR title. The ``push`` payload shows this in ``head_commit`` : ``"message": "Adding a .gitignore file",`` .

Answer (score -1):

Use `github.event.pull_request.title` in your GitHub action..

From here: [How to get the title of a Pull Request with Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688092/how-to-get-the-title-of-a-pull-request-with-github-actions)

> run: echo The Title of your PR is ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}