# How to get the title of a Pull Request with Github Actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

In GitHub I have a pull request called `[WIP] Dev-123 Sample Pull Request`.

I want to get this title in a GitHub Actions yaml pipeline.

In the [GitHub Docs Context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) I can't seem to find which object I need to reference.

Comment: How is your workflow triggered? If it's triggered on `pull_request`, then the title will be in the the event.

Comment: @rethab the `github.event_name` returns the branch name not the PR title. I am using `pull_request_target`

Comment: I didn't say `event_name`. You wanna dump the entire context and see which attribute contains the title: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log

Comment: You need to use the`github.event.pull_request.title` variable to get the pull_request title in yiur workflow from a PR event trigger 

Comment: @GuiFalourd that won't always be true, right? I'm using this solution in my workflow, saving to an environment variable, and it just returned an empty string. I was using `github.event.head_commit_message` but that returns a longer string (I guess the body of the commit)

Comment: It might depends on the specific pull_request event that trigger the workflow (some subtypes might not extract the title from the event again). Did you use the  pull_request trigger only, or did you use a specific type with it?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I had just the push trigger. Added a new pull_request. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340011/github-actions-get-pr-title). I think one thing missing in that answer is the event type (pull_request > type > closed)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The title of the Pull Request can be accessed by `github.event.pull_request.title`

The workflow to use this would be:

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
   types: [opened, synchronize]

  print_title_of_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - name : Print Title of PR
      run: echo The Title of your PR is ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
```

Comment: This is the way. You can also get other attributes, like the `body` with `github.event.pull_request.body`. See a full list of attributes in the API response here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#get-a-pull-request

Comment: What about if the event that triggers is a push event?

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer above is unsafe to use and **exposes the workflow to a critical command injection attack**.
User controlled inputs should be sanitized before use.
You can mitigate this by adding an intermediate environment variable

Reference:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
   types: [opened, synchronize]

  print_title_of_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - name : Print Title of PR
      env:
          TITLE: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
      run: echo The Title of your PR is $TITLE
```