# Skip a GitHub Action workflow that is run on successful completion of previous workflow, when the initial trigger was a pull request containing 'WIP'

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, pull-request

## Background / Context

We have two GitHub Action workflows 1. "Build, Test & Package" and 2. "Deploy to UAT".

Workflow (1) is triggered based on:

```
# runs on pull request (change or push) or tag (for release)
on:
  pull_request:
  release:
```

And builds our software, runs unit tests etc and packages up docker containers ready to be run in an environment.

Workflow (2) is then triggered on *successful* completion of workflow (1):

```
on:
  # when the build workflow finished (not necessarily succeeded - that needs the IF below)
  # NOTE: this *always* runs as if from the master branch
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Build, Test & Package"]
    types:
      - completed

  # or manually
  # NOTE: this *always* runs as if from the master branch
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      PACKAGE_VERSION:
        description: "PACKAGE_VERSION"
        required: false
```

Which also needs an 'if' on the first step in the workflow to exclude running for *unsuccessful* executions of workflow (1).

```
if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}
```

## Question

What I'd like to do, is EXCLUDE running the deployment workflow (2) when the initial pull request that kicks off the whole pipeline starting with (1) has "WIP" in its name somewhere.

Basically this is to avoid polluting our UAT environment with any build other than a current nominated 'current' PR, whilst still allowing our CI pipeline to run to verify tests etc for ALL pull requests even if they are 'WIP'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can [get the title of a Pull Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692835/6309), that means you can also set a variable (IE "[set an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)") to 'true' in (1), your first job.

And you can use that same variable in (2), as a condition for its execution.

```yaml
# runs on pull request (change or push) or tag (for release)
on:
  pull_request:
  release:


jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set WIP variable
        run: |
          if [[ ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }} == *"WIP"* ]]; then
            echo "WIP is in the pull request title"
            echo "wip=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "WIP is not in the pull request title"
            echo "wip=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
        id: wip
```

And for the second job:

```yaml
  my-other-job:
    needs: my-job
    if: needs.my-job.outputs.wip == 'false'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Do something else
        run: |
          echo "This job will only run if WIP is false"
```

---

But if those two jobs are in separate workflows, you will need to use in (1) an action like "[Set environment variables](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-environment-variables)"

- record your environment variables:

```yaml
    echo "wip=true" > ./.github/variables/myvars.env
```

Then in (2), restore you recorded environment variables:

```yaml
- name: Set Environment Variables
  uses: tw3lveparsecs/github-actions-setvars@latest
  with:
    envFilePath: ./.github/variables/myvars.env
```