# Extract version from Github PR title

Tags: android, github, github-actions, cicd

I'm building Android CD Pipeline on Github action to automate app deployment to play store. Currently I'm able to update the `versionCode` using [android-version-action](https://github.com/chkfung/android-version-actions) action.

But on Google Play console version name is "1" only as not finding way to update this.

So I come up with solution when I raise PR from **development** to **master** branch my PR title will be as `Android App Release V1.0.0`

I'm looking for help to extract this `1.0.0` from PR title. So I can update the `versionName` & release artifact directly through github actions without any human interaction.

Currently this is my cd pipeline :

```
name: Android CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Deploy Android App
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set Up JDK 18
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '18'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Bump version code
        uses: chkfung/android-version-actions@v1.2
        with:
          gradlePath: app/build.gradle.kts
          versionCode: ${{github.run_number}}
```

**Edit :** using this `${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}` command I can fetch title. but how can I get versionName from it which will be like `1.0.0`.

Comment: have you looked at thishttps://stackoverflow.com/a/71692835/2243178 ?

Comment: @ThaiPD please check updated question(Edit)

Comment: @SwapnilMusale Can I know how the existing PR title looks like (the one from which you need to extract `1.0.0`)?

Comment: @RobinThomas I am willing to add PR title as ```Android App Release V1.0.0```

Comment: No, I mean the title of the PR from which you want to extract the `1.0.0` from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [this topic](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10553), you can see that GitHub actions is not very open to manipulate strings (at least for now).
I can suggest some of alternative solutions:

- Just simply put the PR title as `V1.0.0`, unless you have a multiple platforms project, what other than Android release you are going to release?
- Or, you can just put a git TAG for a new release, then fetch and manipulate the release version via Gradle (or kotlin kts)

Comment: Thank for the suggestion about tag approach